# Extracting a numeric string from URL

Tags: google-sheets, re2

I was trying to extract this numeric string: `232546102069` from the given link:

```
http://www.abc.in/itm/fawf-asdfsafjsaf-jasfh-lbadfugo-hasdhf-asdijfh-xpq/232546102069?hash=item3624d3eb35:g:BU4AAOSwm3pZ-cQV
```

using regex in Sheets.

Can anyone help me with the logic and its explanation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This _might_ work: Match `http:\/\/www.*\/(\d+)\?` and then check the first capture group.

Comment: please provide rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try matching the following pattern:

```
http:\/\/www.*\/(\d+)\?
```

The number you want to capture will be available in the first capture group.  I make the assumption here that the 12 digit number you want to capture will always occur immediately before the start of the query string.

### Demo

Comment: for some of the links the regex wasn't capturing the required data. But if i removed 'http:' it worked! Can you please explain that?

Comment: The only explanation that comes to mind is that certain of your links do not start with `http`.  Maybe they are fragments, or maybe they start with `https` instead.  Your sample data is very limited, hence I gave what I thought was the best possible answer.